# TestWatcher with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I have implemented TestWatcher to do certain things based on test output, however the function that i need to call which is createScreenShot in testFailed needs a driver as incoming property, sadly driver is protected and not static since all my tests running at the same time.

Trying to achieve: to have a screenshot of each failed test.

What have i tried: I tried adding an additional instance property to the class and pass it to the constructor but i get a failure with the following exception

```
TestResultLoggerExtension.<init>()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.opngo.nowos.utils.TestResultLoggerExtension.<init>()
```

WebSettings

```
@ExtendWith(TestResultLoggerExtension.class)
public class WebDriverSettings {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected String TARGET_URL;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions()
                .addArguments("--headless")
                .addArguments("window-size=1920x1480"));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        loginToEnvironment();
    }

    public class TestResultLoggerExtension implements TestWatcher, AfterAllCallback {
        
        @Override
        public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
            ScreenShotCreator.takeScreenShot(); <- driver needs to get here somehow since on any failed test i need to snap a screenshot
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ExtensionContext` and Reflection to retrieve the `WebDriver` instance in your `TestWatcher`:

```
    Object test = extensionContext.getRequiredTestInstance();
    Field field = test.getClass().getDeclaredField("driver");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) field.get(test);
```

If the `WebDriver` is not declared in the test class but inherited, use e.g. `test.getClass().getSuperclass()` or loop through all superclasses.

The methods in `TestWatcher` get invoked after the methods with @AfterAll/Each annotations. If you quit your WebDriver there, move it to your `TestWatcher`.